# How to access my local file on my server like apache

Tags: html, apache, service, google-drive-api, local-files

If you have used apache server. Then we can access our local files inside /var/www/html on apache web page because if we add any file or folder in to this directory then it automatically links our file to webpage and we can navigate through them . so my question is that, i am going to host my site on google drive and want to make webpage like this which automatically links my files and folders to webpage from the location i am hosting or any other location. It should be also link my files to webpage automatically as i put any file or folder inside it , can i do it with html,css and javascript or i will have to use any other service.

Comment: I think google drive already has a web ui with file listing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to even try this. What you are explaining is very dangerous in terms of security. *"automatically links my files and folders to webpage from the location i am hosting or any other location"*

You are opening yourself up for XSS (Cross site scripting) attacks. If you can display any remote file on your website, so can an attacker.

Find a reputable web host and store you website files in a secure manner.